# Is there any way to edit big size AWS Lambda function online?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Currently I am working with AWS Lambda in my Vue.js project.
In the AWS Lambda console, this message is displayed.

```
"The deployment package of your Lambda function "GraphqlResolver-yukidev" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function."
```

The file which needs change is only one.
The size of function is too big so I want to work with only this file.
So are there anyway to edit this Lambda function online or alternative ways?

Comment: Separate the dependencies into a Lambda layer.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/